# How can I access Probuilders actual object size instead of the Unitys object size in Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im knew to Unity and I'm trying to find the scale of a probuilder object for a 3D game I am working on

The information I am trying to access is right here so it should be possible (The "ObjectSize (read only)" variables for x,y,z)

[image]

I just need to store the different scales in a variable so I can continue with my program and not have to manually input the data myself in a SerializedField.

Ive tried the following:

```
DebugLog(transform.localScale);
```

```
private ProBuilderMesh objects
objects = GetComponent<ProBuilderMesh>();
Debug.Log(objects.transform.localScale)
```

```
var objects = GetComponent<Renderer>();
var bounds = objects.bounds;
Debug.Log(bounds);
```

Ive tried a few other things but I can't remember them and most returned errors

Any help would be greatly appriciated!

Comment: Does this help? https://forum.unity.com/threads/probuilder-5-0-6-object-size-read-only.1330338/
They talk about setting the size, but I'd imagine you can get it this way as well.

Comment: I looked at that thread but I couldnt figure out how to access the script referenced

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, ProBuilder does not follow normal conventions for its exposed API, so ObjectSize is not an exposed property, nor is ProBuilder MeshFilter, a MeshFilter (if you do right click->Edit Script, you'll see it takes you to a class called ProBuilderMesh). Also the ProBuilderShape class is private and sealed so it's inaccessible for referencing in your scripts.

Regardless, in both cases, the Size you see comes from Renderer Bounds.
In the image below, you can see a New Shape, created by ProBuilder. It has the ProBuilderShape attached as well.

The size in ProBuilderShape is what the mesh itself occupies if it has scale 1,1,1. The ObjectSize in ProBuilderMeshFilter is the ProBuilderShape's value scaled by 0.29 ( 709.4 * 0.29 =  205.726).

Same thing applies when you just have a ProBuilderMeshFilter component without the ProBuilderShape. The ObjectSize is the Renderer.Bounds affected by scale.

Note that the Renderer.Bounds will give you Extents which is half of whatever is displayed in the aforementioned fields, per axis.

[image]